# Get text from pressed button

Tags: android

How can I get the text from a pressed button? (Android)

I can get the text from a button:

```
String buttonText = button.getText();
```

I can get the id from a pressed button:

```
int buttinID = view.getId();
```

What I can't find out at this moment is how to get the text on the pressed button.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
  // Get the text on the pressed button
}
```

Answer (score 180, accepted):

The view you get passed in on `onClick()` is the Button you are looking for.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // 1) Possibly check for instance of first 
    Button b = (Button)v;
    String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
}
```

1) If you are using a non-anonymous class as `onClickListener`, you may want to check for the
type of the view before casting it, as it may be something different than a Button.

Comment: Thanks, it works after adding .tostring() to it like Scythe says :) I forgot to cast it to a Button object first.

Comment: Any idea why simply `````
String buttonText = (Button) v).getText().toString(); `````` would not work?

Comment: That should be good too (except for the one missing paren), the above just made it more obvious

Comment: Is it possible somehow avoid storing Button to variable, and directly cast pressed view element to button.

Answer (score 8):

If you're sure that the OnClickListener instance is applied to a Button, then you could just cast the received view to a Button and get the text:

```
public void onClick(View view){
Button b = (Button)view;
String text = b.getText().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try to use:

```
String buttonText = ((Button)v).getText().toString();
```

Comment: This will work but you have to cast it to String. So it's: `String s = (String) ((Button)v).getText();`

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
String btnText=btn.getText();
```

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener { doSomething((it as Button).text) }
```

Note: This gets the button text as a `CharSequence`, which more places in code can likely use. If you really want a String from there, then you can use `.toString()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
String btnText=btn.getText().toString();
```

Later this `btnText` can be used .

For example:

```
if(btnText == "Text for comparison")
```

Comment: This is practically a copy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/47768827/7733418, with a little from the upvoted answer mixed in, isn't it? If it is not, then please explain the difference and why it is necessary to answer the question. Explaining code-only answers also helps fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

Typecast the view into a button and access the text content using `getText()`.

```
   public String onClick(View view) {
        // Get the text on the pressed button
        return ((Button)view).getText().toString()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Import text from button to string
String b_text = button.getText().toString();
// To set button text
button.setText("xyz");
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32590439)