# Detect which button was pressed

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, tablerow

Here's my situation:
I programmatically give some buttons an onClickListener, however, I can't fully-handle this event, because I'd like to detect which button was pressed to give to that button (when it is pressed) a new value. Here's how I program those buttons:

```
  final View.OnClickListener soundButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playSound(1);

                int x = songPlay * songProgress;

                mplayer.seekTo(x);
            }
        };

        tableLayout = (TableLayout)v
                .findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

        int number = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < tableLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            TableRow row = (TableRow)tableLayout.getChildAt(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < row.getChildCount(); j++) {
                Button button = (Button) row.getChildAt(j);
                button.setText("" + number);

                button.setOnClickListener(soundButtonListener);
                songProgress = j;
                number++;
            }
        }
```

As you see, they haven't a click listener for each one, so when I press my button, mplayer always seekto a point, becausae songProgress stops at 64 (I have 64 buttons to handle). What is good is that I have a number for each button (as you see button.setText("" + number);), and I'd like to check what is their number to give to songProgress different values.

Comment: can you please elaborate more. it is not much clear to me

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for.
[Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412180/how-to-determine-which-button-pressed-on-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i correctly understand you can do something like this:

```
final View.OnClickListener soundButtonOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v instanceof Button) {
            Button button = (Button) v;
            String text = button.getText().toString();

            if(text == "1") {
                //...
            } else if(text == "2") {

            }
            //OR
            switch (text) {
                case "1": {
                    break;
                }
                case "2": {
                    break;
                }
                //...
            }
        }
    }
};
```

But in my opinion better use tag instead of text:

```
//set tag for your button
button.setTag(number); 

//use this tag
Integer number = (Integer) v.getTag();
if(number != null) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: It doesn't totally work, because it gets 0 value from the button

Comment: @BitleApps What do you mean?

Comment: I solved this problem, but my "x" doesn't increment (Songplay is not 0)

Answer (score 0):

Your `onClick` has a `View v` Object which should be the view that triggered the event. So this view should be your button.
Now you could get the text of that button with `v.getText()`. Then parse the text to your number and use it.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to know the text of the pressed button, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5620816/4782930):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button b = (Button)v;
    String buttonText = b.getText().toString();

    //Do your thing with buttonText
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to detect your button. Simply you can do like

```
button.setId(2000 + 0);
```

for reference you can check it -

```
  for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
     Button button = new Button(this);
     button.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
     button.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
     if (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(ch[i])) == 0) {
            button.setText("No");
            button.setId(2000 + 0);
            layout.addView(button, layoutParams);
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        if (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(ch[i])) == 1) {
            button.setText("Less");
            button.setId(2000 + 1);
            layout.addView(button, layoutParams);
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        if (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(ch[i])) == 2) {
            button.setText("Half");
            button.setId(2000 + 2);
            layout.addView(button, layoutParams);
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
}
```

and in onClick

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case 2000:
            Log.e(TAG,"button 0 clicked");
            break;
        case 2001:
            Log.e(TAG,"button 1 clicked");
            break;
        case 2002:
            Log.e(TAG,"button 2 clicked");
            break;
        case 2003:
            Log.e(TAG,"button 3 clicked");
            break;
    }
}
```